# Hive Metastore Standalone and Apache Ranger Integration

Tags: docker, hive-metastore, apache-ranger

I'm trying to integrate HMS Standalone version and Apache Ranger Hive Plug-in. I've compiled the ranger-2.4.0-hive-plugin from source code of Ranger 2.4.0.

Situation:

1. Ranger Admin runs as Docker.
2. Hive Metastore Standalone is also runs in Docker with Hive Plugin enabled.

> Ranger Plugin for hive has been enabled. Please restart hive to ensure that changes are effective.

I can verify the installation with this message.

3. There is no connection problem between two container. I can verify it the command;

   curl  -u user:pass -X GET http://ranger_host:port/service/public/v2/api/service/ |jq
4. Both systems are up and running (as containerized). I've set log level to TRACE via log4j.But I can not see anything the HMS logs related to Apache Ranger Hive Plugin.

But /etc/ranger/hmstest/policycache directory is empty. Also Ranger logs does not container any exception related to HMS.

I can get the policy via Rest API Ranger for hmstest service. hmstest is defined as Hadoop SQL Service in Ranger Admin.

But it seems there is no agent to get policies on Hive Metastore Standalone Service.

I am using open jdk 11. Also I verified the metastore-site.xml and it containers Ranger Related configurations.

Any idea, what can cause the problem?

Used HMS: https://downloads.apache.org/hive/hive-standalone-metastore-3.0.0/hive-standalone-metastore-3.0.0-bin.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to enforce standalone Hive Metastore (HMS) directly, but Ranger enforces security for Hive through Hive Server2 (HS2). If your goal is to achieve direct enforcement for the metastore, you have two options:

1. Configure HMS with an external database for which Ranger has a plugin. Enforce security policies on this external database using Ranger. In this scenario, you would be using a plugin specific to the external database, not the `ranger-2.4.0-hive-plugin`.
2. (**This might be complicated**) Hive-4 is not released yet, but the following Jira enables direct HMS enforcement in Hive https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-21753. In this case, you need to use Hive-4-alpha instead of Hive-3, uncomment this [block](https://github.com/apache/ranger/blob/release-ranger-2.4.0/hive-agent/src/main/java/org/apache/ranger/authorization/hive/authorizer/RangerHiveAuthorizer.java#L162-L171) in Ranger and recompiled the plugin (this might be just a trivial issue, not 100% sure), and as a last step configure Hive to use HMS as pre event listener:

```xml
<property>
<name>hive.security.authorization.manager</name>
<value>org.apache.ranger.authorization.hive.authorizer.RangerHiveAuthorizerFactory</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.metastore.pre.event.listeners</name> 
<value>...,org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.metastore.HiveMetaStoreAuthorizer,...</value>
</property>
```

Apache Ranger community has not take any specific actions regarding HMS integration, and the second option might be challenging. However, if configured correctly, you should see HMS as a service in the Ranger Admin UI as below:

[image]

Comment: I couldn't get point for first option. I try to restrict access to specific tables, columns and maybe data masking on columns. Let's assume HMS is installed externally db with Postgres. If I create for that database users would be restircted to specific tables and columns.  So I could not figure out that if users can't access a metastore db metadata database, how would if work for data which are stored in the metadata database. Users will be restirected for; hms_db.hms_schema.columns table but I try to create a restirection for another table which is stored same table.

Comment: I'll will review second options if I understand correctly first option.

Comment: I understand your concern about the first option. It is all up to database you choose and capabilities of the corresponding plugin in this case. For example Trino (Presto) can handle database/table/column level enforcements. You can specify all those parameters `hms_db.hms_schema.columns` in your policies along with users/groups. So, in this case you would know which user can access to what. There are some details in this tutorial https://towardsdatascience.com/integrating-trino-and-apache-ranger-b808f6b96ad8